# SQL update/delete performance with using BATCH execution vs single statement with IN clause?

Tags: sql, relational-database, database-performance, sqlperformance

Lets say I have TABLE T with columns COL1, COL2, COL3.

I am wondering which of these two options would be better in terms of performance?

```
1) DELETE FROM T WHERE COL1 = <something> AND COL2 = <something> AND COL3 in (a, b, c, d, ... , z);

2) Create BATCH containing:
    DELETE FROM T WHERE COL1 = <something> AND COL2 = <something> AND COL3 = a
    DELETE FROM T WHERE COL1 = <something> AND COL2 = <something> AND COL3 = b
    DELETE FROM T WHERE COL1 = <something> AND COL2 = <something> AND COL3 = c
    DELETE FROM T WHERE COL1 = <something> AND COL2 = <something> AND COL3 = d
    .....
    DELETE FROM T WHERE COL1 = <something> AND COL2 = <something> AND COL3 = z
```

I would be interest to know if there will be any difference with small number of rows and huge number of rows?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The first option should be faster as you are running only a single query, so there's less overheads. However, if you run the batch queries as parameterized queries, the query engine should be able to buffer the queries, and the difference should thus be small.

This assumes you have an index on columns 1 and/or 2 to filter. If you don't, the first approach will always be way faster, parameterized or not.

Perhaps the only case I can think of where the 2nd approach would be faster is when you only have a hash index on all three columns combined - then the query optimizer may not be smart enough to utilize the index in the first approach (depending when DB vendor you use).

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the Recovery Model of your database combined with the Indexing on the table.

If you are in a situation where your Deletes are fully logged then do it in Batches.(Full Recovery & Indexes on Table)

If you meet the conditions for minimal logging then do the whole lot in one go.
(Simple & Heap)

Do a search on "Traceflag 610" you'll get some really helpful advice.

Comment: This is highly product specific. Which DBMS are you talking about?

Comment: I'm talking about SQL Server, but the principle of Logging is relevant to maintaining any database's ACID properties.

Comment: You are right about "logging" but that is implemented **very** differently in different DBMS. Plus things like "recovery model",  "simple vs. heap" or "traceflag 610" do not exist in other DBMS.